# Change background color of a custom wordpress html block with additional CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I’m trying to change the background color of a custom html WordPress block, but when I access this block, I change the background color of all custom html blocks from other pages

this is the CSS instruction I am using:

`#main.site-main.post-single.order-first{ background-color:  #212529; }`

I expected the background color of the custom html block to only be changed on this page, however it was also changed on another page which also has a custom html block

Comment: Please add your HTML code also for a better understanding. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

In the block settings in the Wordpress editor (i.e. the column at the right side of the window), there is the option to assign a *class* to a block (all the way at the bottom of the column). Do that, use a unique name for it and create a CSS rule for that class with the desired settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a custom html, you can always add unique class to wrapper tag, and apply any styles to this specific element:
[image]

Your CSS code in this case should look like this:

```
.my-unique-block { background-color:  #212529; }
```

If you don't have an access to html, try to find the specific postid id class pointing to your block, like `postid-17` and change to:

```
#main.site-main.postid-17.order-first{ background-color:  #212529; }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this..

```
#main.site-main.post-single.order-first{ background-color:  #212529!important; }
```